# In Unity, on an Android device, CaptureScreenshot writing to Phone, but persistentdatapath linking to the external card

Tags: android, unity, file, screenshot

I'm using `CaptureScreentshot()` to get an image. But when I try to access it on an Android device it's giving me:
`Could not find file "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appname/screenshot.png"`

When I go the external storage, it's not there, but rather on the phone storage. So why is persistentdatapath accessing something different?

My code is the following:
`byte[] Bytes_File = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(currentScreenshotPathname);` with thepathname obtained using:
`currentScreenshotPathname = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, currentScreenshotName);`

Is there anyway to make the persistenDataPath go to the phone storage rather than emulated to read the file? I've tried changing the `WriteAccess` perimission to `External`as well as `Internal` in the player settings, but it's still the same.

Edit: Here's what's happening:
PersistentDataPath is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/, but the screenshot is being saved to /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files, despite the documentation saying that it should save to the PersistentDataPath.

Comment: Have your tried adding it as a resource, then getting its uri? 
I'm not sure how to do it, but I know that Android doesn't like it when you use file paths.

Comment: The thing is, the documentation says it's being saved to Application.persistentDataPath, but it's not. I'm not sure if this is a bug in Unity or not..

Comment: PersistentDataPath is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/, but instead it's being saved to /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a custom method to take screenshots and save them wherever you want ?

I use this method in my games:

```
    private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot(string screen_path)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        int width = Screen.width;
        int height = Screen.height;
        // Creates a new texture of the size of your screen.
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        // Reads every pixel displayed on the screen.
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();

        // Save the screenshot as a byte array.
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
        Destroy(tex);
        // Save the screenshot on disk.
        File.WriteAllBytes(screen_path, bytes);
        Debug.Log("Screenshot (" + screen_path + ") saved!");
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I switched to using something similar. I'm going to accept your response in case someone else has that problem. :D